# MySQL, PHP. Best way to upload and update multiple files

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating for my school project php form which allows to upload (and edit) 10 media files (media_1, media_2... in db) to ftp and store their names in db.

```
+----+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| id | user    | media_1 | media_2  | media_3  | media_4  |
+----+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1  | user_1  | name_1  | name_2   | name_3   | name_4   |
+----+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| 2  | user_2  | name_11 | name_21  | name_32  | name_42  |
+----+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

What is the best way to do it?

- It is not a problem to upload files and store them in db
- problem is when I am allowing user to edit any of those photos. User can edit 0, 1, 2,..., 10 photos (in one php form with one submit). I can create separate query for every single media_file, check if new file was selected and then if was update its name in db, but it is probably not good solution. I was thinking of a loop with a dynamically changing column name, but I found in another topics, that it's also not good way. Maybe I should in someway redesign table?

Any advices would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Start by fixing your database layout - do proper _normalization_. That means, not having x different, “numbered” columns for images to begin with - but creating an extra table, that associates the user id with _one_ single image.

Comment: Yep. Have a separate media table. If a photo can belong tom more than one user then you need a further junction table, recording which image belongs to thich user, otherwise you can simply store the user in the image table.